# Is there any value in a Windows 98 license?

Tags: license, windows-98

Cleaning up some old papers, I found a Windows 98 license certificate.  Does this have any value at all, or should I just toss it?

Answer (score 4):

As far as for people who want to buy it for use, probably not. It is unsupported and it doesn't seem that Microsoft cares if people have the key.

For nostalgia, perhaps. It goes for like $20 on Ebay.

Comment: hmm really ? Oh wells, I set fire to my last 98 licence.

Answer (score 4):

No, Too many key generators out there for win98, and Microsoft does not protect installations with WGA or any type of activation scheme, besides most of the hardware that can even run W98 has been recycled.

About all you can say is you own a piece of computer history, since it does not take up much room, archive it for the grandkids.

Comment: I still have the full set of 3.5" Windows 2.11 floppies for nostalgia purposes.

Comment: My brother has a sealed in the bag set of W98 floppies, woohoo! Maybe the grandchildren can eBay them in 2075 to buy some Soylent Green..

Comment: Wish I'd though of that when I tossed a sealed pack of Win95 _beta_ floppies during our office move a few months back.  My grandchildren will have to resort to motorcycle racing or spice smuggling.

Answer (score 2):

I will save it in Evernote or similar note-taking application, as a photo scan. If you ever need it, you will have it.

Answer (score 2):

It possibly has a very nominal value. Probably best just to bin it.
You could offer it up on Freecycle or something like that. Doubt you'd have any takers though.